# Easel hangs off the enlarger baseboard - how to keep the easel level?

Tags: darkroom, enlarging

I am setting up my first darkroom. I purchased an Omega D2 and an 11x14 enlarging easel that takes up 14x17. I immediately noticed that when I tried to position the easel under the image, most print sizes forced one or more "legs" of the easel off of the enlarging baseboard. This means the easel hangs out over the baseboard and is slightly off the plane of focus.

One solution is to not make prints that big, obviously, so I could buy a smaller easel. I'd rather make this easel work, however. How can I keep things perfectly level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the D2 is bolted to its base so you can detach it. Depending on the counter or surface you are using you could bolt it directly to the counter. ( that is what i would do )

You could replace the base with a larger board if you wanted it to be mobile on your counter top.  I would use at least 3/4 cabinet grade plywood and sand it smooth round over the edges and put several coats of a protective finish on it.

I seem to remember a wall mount kit available for it as well. Try ebay.

A more minimal approach would be to measure the thickness of its base and just make couple of pieces of wood of the same thickness and put them under the legs that are hanging over.